# Is there a list of reserved words in ANTLR grammars?

Tags: antlr

I recently created an ANTLR3 parser rule

```
options : foo bar;
```

which didn't compile and it took me some time to discover that `options` was a reserved word (AntlrWorks indicated an error but not why). Is there a list of reserved words in ANTLR and are there best practices in naming rules (which might help avoid this)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reserved words of ANTLR v3 are:

```
    Keyword  |  Description
    ---------+--------------------------------------------------------
    scope    |  Dynamically-scoped attribute
    fragment |  lexer rule is a helper rule, not real token for parser
    lexer    |  grammar type
    tree     |  grammar type
    parser   |  grammar type
    grammar  |  grammar header
    returns  |  rule return value(s)
    throws   |  rule throws exception(s)
    catch    |  catch rule exceptions
    finally  |  do this no matter what
    options  |  grammar or rule options
    tokens   |  can add tokens with this; usually imaginary tokens
    import   |  import grammar(s)
```

See: https://web.archive.org/web/20120314155217/http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+Cheat+Sheet (at the end of the page)

Don't know  of a "naming convention" w.r.t. parser rules (other than they should start with a lower case, which is not convention, of course...).

Comment: Thanks! I wondered if I shoulde use pseudonamespaced names such as init_a, init_b, ... to avoid clashes if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Using the reserved words of your target language can also cause problems.

I spent a day trying to figure out why my grammar wouldn't work only to realize it was getting messed up by the "enum" rule in my grammar I had named "enum".

This may or may not be an issue depending on what the target language is.  I was using the default Java target, and it certainly was, so if that's the case you should check the list of reserved keywords for your target language as well.

Comment: Could you expand the explanation please?

Comment: 2018, v4: rules with names like `getTokenNames` will end up as methods in parser's code, and make `javac` compilation fail.