# antlr4: why is `tree` unusable as a rule name?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

If I save the grammar

```
grammar L;

tree: 't' ;
a: tree | 'b' ;
```

in a file name `L.g4` and invoke `antlr4 L.g4` (Version 4.7.1) , it outputs an incomprehensible error message without any line or column numbers:

> L.g4::: syntax error: mismatched character '|' expecting 'g'

The `:::` part is where the line/column numbers of the errors usually go.

If I instead save

```
grammar L;

tre: 't' ;
a: tre | 'b' ;
```

as `L.g4` and run `antlr4` on it, it runs without errors.

What's wrong with the `tree` identifier? It's not listed in the list of [reserved keywords](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexicon.md#keywords):

> import, fragment, lexer, parser, grammar, returns,
>   locals, throws, catch, finally, mode, options, tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tree` is a [reserved keyword in ANTLR v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818664/is-there-a-list-of-reserved-words-in-antlr-grammars). I guess the documentation could be incomplete or it could be a bug. The documentation also mentions non-keywords that can't be used as rule name (like the word `rule`), so it's possible that `tree` is similar - not a real keyword yet not allowed everywhere.

According to this [unresolved ANTRL4 bug report for your issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1960), it works if you remove the space between `tree` and `:`.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918884/2707792) also seems still relevant, it seems that it will happily use the unescaped rule names as method names in Java code: `public final BobbyTablesContext bobbyTables()`. I guess nothing good will happen if I use `throw` or `private` instead of `bobbyTables`. Thanks, I'll try to be a bit more careful with the choice of the rule names. (Minor correction: `throw` actually generates nice error message.)